# Launch Image doesn't load on iOS 8

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using Xcode 6.1. I'm making game app for iOS 6.1, iOS 7's and iOS 8. I added launch images in all proper sizes for iOS 5,6,7,8. If i had a size issue Xcode would tell me but i have no errors in Xcode. In Launch Image source i clicked on LaunchImage. I don't understand why for only iOS 8 launch image doesn't load. Simulator loads directly into game. Also, doesn't matter if it's iPhone 4s, 5's, or 6. All iOS 8 don't load launch image. What can be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

On your general settings panel, do you see **Launch Screen File**?  In iOS 8, your app by default will load the LaunchScreen.xib instead of showing a static image.  On iOS 7 and earlier, it will use the launch image you set up -- and you might want to use your Asset Catalog for that if you just want an image.

If you *do* just want an image, drag a UIImageView into your LaunchImage.xib and set your launch image as the default image.

Comment: So i just made a LaunchScreen.xib file. In that file I put my Retina HD 4.7 inch launch image for the 4.7 inch screen. In Launch Screen File I put as LaunchScreen.xib I still get the same result. iOS 7 launch images load but iOS 8 launch images don't load.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before. Just delete the launch image for iOS 8, and it will work under iOS 8.

If you are supporting iOS 6, 7, just don't set any assets specifically for iOS 8 (forget iOS 8), because if you do, iOS 8 will not simply "enlarge" your app, you will be responsible for the layouts on the larger screen of iPhone 6 and plus, which may requires you to revise many auto layout constraints in your app to get them right.